# Uniform convergence of piecewise defined function

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

I have solved the following exercise and I would like to know if I have made any mistakes. Thank you.

Problem: Let $h_n(x)=$
\begin{cases}
                                1 & \text{if $x=\frac{1}{n}$}\\
                                x & \text{if $x=1,\frac{1}{2},\dots,\frac{1}{n-1}$}\\
                                0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
and let $h$ be the pointwise limit of $h_n$. Is each $h_n$ continuous at $0$? Does $h_n\to h$ uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$? Is $h$ continuous at $0$?

My solution:

Let $\varepsilon>0$, fix $n\geq 1$ and set $\delta:=\frac{1}{n}$: then $|x-0|<\delta$ implies $|h_n(x)-h_n(0)|=|h_n(x)-0|=|h_n(x)|=0<\varepsilon$ (note that $h\equiv 0$ for $x\in [0,\frac{1}{n})$) so each $h_n$ is continuous at $0$. Now, let $N\geq 1$, and $m,n\geq N$ (we can assume wlog $m>n$): then $|h_m(x)-h_n(x)|=$
\begin{cases}
                                0 & \text{if $x=1,\frac{1}{2},\dots,\frac{1}{n-1},\frac{1}{n}$} \\
                                x & \text{if $x=\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n+2},\dots,\frac{1}{m-1}$} \\
                                1 & \text{$x=\frac{1}{m}$} \\
                                0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
so if we pick $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{2}$ we have $|h_m(\frac{1}{m})-h_n(\frac{1}{2m})|=|1-0|=1>\varepsilon$. So we have shown there exists a $\varepsilon>0$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that for all $N\geq 1$ and $m,n\geq N$ we have $|h_m(x)-h_n(x)|=1>\varepsilon$ thus by the Cauchy Criterion for Uniform Convergence we have that $h_n$ does not uniformly converge on $\mathbb{R}$.

EDIT: (first part is fine, following second part corrected according to answer below by José Carlos Santos)

Now, let $\varepsilon>0$ and set $\delta:=\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$: then $|x-0|<\delta$ implies $|h(x)-h(0)|=|h(x)-0|=|h(x)|\leq\frac{\varepsilon}{2}<\varepsilon$ so $h$ is continuous at $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You proved correctly that the convergence is not uniform. However, $h$ *is* continuous at $0$, since$$h(x)=\begin{cases}x&\text{ if }x\in\left\{1,\frac12,\frac13,\ldots\right\}\\0&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

Comment: what stopped me from concluding that $h$ is of the form you wrote is the $h(x)=1$ if $x=\frac{1}{n}$: I figured in the limiting case I would always have had a term very close to $0$ where $h$ has value 1. Could you give me some intuition behind how that term goes away in the pointwise limit? Thank you very much.

Comment: Think about this simpler example:$$h(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{ if }x=\frac1n\\0&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$Then you always have $h\left(\frac1n\right)=1$, right?! However, $(h_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converge pointwise to the null function.

Comment: I have found another similar question (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2160164/uniform-convergence-of-sequences-of-piecewise-functions) where the answer says that such a function is not continuous at $0$. I am confused.

Comment: In that exercise, $f(x)=1$ if $x\in\left\{\frac12,\frac13,\frac14,\ldots\right\}$ and $f(x)=0$ otherwise. So, $f(0)=0$ and there are points $x_0$ arbitrarily close to $0$ at which $f(x_0)=1$. So, $f$ is discontinuous at $0$ then indeed.

Comment: Ok, I see it now: than you very much for your time and help.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.